# libjpeg wont link with opencv on android

Tags: android, opencv, libjpeg

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_core
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_core.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_calib3d
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_calib3d.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_videostab
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_videostab.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_videoio
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_videoio.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_video
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_video.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_shape
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_shape.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

ifeq ($(APP_ABI),armeaby-v7a)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_ts
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_ts.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

endif

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_superres
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_superres.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_stitching
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_stitching.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_photo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_photo.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_flann
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_flann.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_objdetect
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_objdetect.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_ml
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_ml.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_imgcodecs
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_imgcodecs.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_features2d
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_features2d.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_highgui
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_highgui.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopencv_imgproc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libopencv_imgproc.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libtbb
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/3rdparty/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libtbb.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libIlmImf
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/3rdparty/libs/$(APP_ABI)/libIlmImf.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := liblibjasper
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/3rdparty/libs/$(APP_ABI)/liblibjasper.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := liblibjpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/3rdparty/libs/$(APP_ABI)/liblibjpeg.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := liblibpng
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/3rdparty/libs/$(APP_ABI)/liblibpng.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := liblibtiff
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/3rdparty/libs/$(APP_ABI)/liblibtiff.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := liblibwebp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/3rdparty/libs/$(APP_ABI)/liblibwebp.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/eigen\
$(LOCAL_PATH)/inc\
$(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv_precompiled/include\

LOCAL_MODULE:=blend
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=$(LOCAL_PATH)/src/poisson_solver.cpp $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/clone.cpp $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/seamless_cloning.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lz -llog -landroid -ldl -lm -ljnigraphics
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libopencv_shape libopencv_stitching libopencv_objdetect libopencv_superres libopencv_videostab libopencv_calib3d\
libopencv_features2d libopencv_highgui libopencv_videoio libopencv_imgcodecs libopencv_video libopencv_photo\
libopencv_ml libopencv_imgproc libopencv_flann libopencv_core\
liblibjpeg liblibwebp liblibpng liblibtiff liblibjasper libIlmImf libtbb\

ifeq ($(APP_ABI),armeaby-v7a)
LOCAL_LDLIBS += libopencv_ts
endif

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := cpu_info-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/utils.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
APP_ABI := arm64-v8a
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11 -fexceptions
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

This is the error i get:

```
/home/pedja/workspace/Projekat/android/src/main/jni/opencv_precompiled/libs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg.cpp.o): In function `cv::my_jpeg_load_dht(jpeg_decompress_struct*, unsigned char*, JHUFF_TBL**, JHUFF_TBL**) [clone .constprop.52]':
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text.unlikely._ZN2cvL16my_jpeg_load_dhtEP22jpeg_decompress_structPhPP9JHUFF_TBLS5_.constprop.52+0x104): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table'
/home/pedja/workspace/Projekat/android/src/main/jni/opencv_precompiled/libs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg.cpp.o): In function `cv::JpegEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
```

Full error:
[Error](http://pastebin.com/Hdhj76u0)

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question.

For some reason, module name for local static libraries cannot be: "liblibjpeg" for example. 
After renaming module `liblibjpeg` (and other libs that start with lib) to `libjpeg` it linked successfully.